# Azure automatically updates bot code from Github but doesn't actually change the code being used. What can I do?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I have a development system using all Microsoft products to ensure compatibility across all systems for this project. I am using:

- Visual Studio 2017
- BotBuilder SDK V4
- Node.js (version 10)
- npm (current version)
- Github
- Azure Pay per Use account
- Bot Web App with all other required subscriptions
- Slack (for external channel)
- Bot Framework Emulator (V4 PREVIEW)

Here's what happened:

I had followed all the tutorials to create the echo bot with the counter as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). This all worked and I connected the bot to Slack. The issue is that I cannot get it to update to my new code.

For example, I run it successfully on my local machine with the emulator and later push changes up to the master branch on Github. **I have Azure set to automatically synchronize with the master branch**, but the changes never occur. This seems bizarre as Azure states that the integration was successful. However, both the Slack channel and the Azure test chat continue to use the same echo bot from the start.

What should I do to force Azure to use the most current version of my bot code?

Here is what I see so far:

[Bot still chats with echo bot, but is disabled in the newest version of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcXdS.png)

[Same Github directory as the original code, "code" is where the files are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6xQ8.png)

[Code section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLxfI.png)

[package.JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Te4f.png)

[autoDeployment from Github appears to work. I have disconnected and reconnected several times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuB4a.png)

[Slack gives errors, but that's because I am using pay per use service with the free version of bot and processing, so very slow. These errors are expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZMIW.png)

Comment: Where and with what settings have you configured the integration. Can you post with some images. Are you referring to **Deployment Options** section. Generally it works as stated, but sometimes, It does not reflect the new changes quickly/automatically, so I disconnect and then setup the integration again. Also how is your project setup. Can you also post the directory structure of the project and at least script section of `package.json`

Comment: Yes, the **Deployment Details** section appears to not update the code correctly. It seems to know exactly when the master is updated and will automatically sync, but never changes the code that is used.

Comment: When you check the code inside of your webapp on azure using `{bot}>Build>Open online code editor` can you see the newest version of your code (i.e. its there but the old one is running) or is it the old version of your code (i.e. it didn't deploy at all)?

Answer (score 1):

Since there has been no official answer, let this suffice to anyone who may experience a similar problem.

I downloaded and saved the scripts for custom bot code. Then deleted all resources on Azure, being sure to restart all those resources with the default echo bot. Once the echo bot is deployed, I copied in my scripts to the directory of the code after updating the package-lock.JSON file. This seemed to work.

So, this is not an official answer from anyone deeply involved in the chatbot research group, but may alleviate a few hours of searching other web pages for a solution that is not clearly defined.